# Hacer operadores sinónimo de operador

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Las siguientes etiquetas tienen como diferencia una ser el plural de la otra. Favor de hacer el plural sinónimo del singular:

[operador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operador) ← [operadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/operadores)

Comment: Ya ha sido creado el sinónimo. Un saludo